# CreateJS click event on sprite not working

Tags: createjs

I'm having trouble with a click event on a sprite in CreateJS.  The event isn't firing as expected.  I've tried:

```
button.addEventListener("click", function() { alert('test'); });
```

and

```
button.on("click", function() { alert('test'); });
```

Neither of them fire on click event.   Any ideas?

Comment: Any chance you have an error in the console? If you are loading images cross-domain, you might be seeing cross-domain errors that prevent your click from firing.

Comment: @Lanny no, the console is clean.  Images are definitely not cross-domain.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.  I forgot to enable the mouse on the stage.

e.g.

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvasId");
//Children of container can dispatch mouse events
stage.mouseChildren = true;
//EaselJS checks 10 times per second what's under mouse pointer
stage.enableMouseOver(10);
```

[CreateJS mouse events tutorial](http://www.createjs.com/tutorials/Mouse%20Interaction/)

Comment: I am glad your app is working now, but the `enableMouseOver` method just makes EaselJS track what is under the mouse during mousemove. Click events are not related to the `enableMouseOver` at all. The `stage.mouseChildren` property defaults to `true`, so neither of these things should contribute to solving an issue with the "click" event on a stage element.